# div used for image display causing difficulties while uploading file;

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here i have a image upload mechanism. It's purpose is to accept an image and display it in a div with id=imageholder . My problem is if i have this image holder div inside my form , it gives upload error (4) . So i get an empty $_FILES array. But if i omit it i get a populated $_FILES array .But i need that div inside the form for design purpose. How i can escape this situation .

with imagehoder div inside form:

[image]

without imageholder div :

[image]

***code may seem long . But none  of it is related to the question. It is generally for validating the mime type***

full code :

```
<?php  print_r($_FILES);?>
<html>
<body>
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
<div id='photouploder'>

   <div id='imagehoder'></div> // creating problem

   <div class="inputWrapper">upload image
       <input class="fileInput" id='up' type="file" name="image"/>
   </div>
</div>
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
<script>
    var imageholder=document.getElementById('imageholder');

function getBLOBFileHeader(url, blob, callback,callbackTwo) {


    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onloadend = function(e) {
    var arr = (new Uint8Array(e.target.result)).subarray(0, 4);
    var header = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        header += arr[i].toString(16);

    }
    var imgtype= callback(url, header);// headerCallback

    callbackTwo(imgtype,blob)

    };

    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);

}



function headerCallback(url, headerString) {

  var info=getHeaderInfo(url, headerString);
  return info;

}

function getTheJobDone(mimetype,blob){

    var mimearray=['image/png','image/jpeg','image/gif'];
    console.log('mimetype is :'+mimetype);
    if(mimearray.indexOf(mimetype) !=-1){
        printImage(blob);
    }else{
        document.getElementById('up').value='';
         while (imageholder.firstChild) {
                  imageholder.removeChild(imageholder.firstChild);
             } 
        console.log('you can not upload this file type');
    }
}

function remoteCallback(url, blob) {


    getBLOBFileHeader(url, blob, headerCallback,getTheJobDone);

}

function printImage(blob) {
  // Add this image to the document body for proof of GET success
  var fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onloadend = function(e) {
     var img=document.createElement('img');
     img.setAttribute('src',e.target.result);
     img.setAttribute('style','width:100%;height:100%;');
     imageholder.appendChild(img);
  };

  fr.readAsDataURL(blob);

}


function mimeType(headerString) {

  switch (headerString) {

    case "89504e47":
      type = "image/png";
      break;
    case "47494638":
      type = "image/gif";
      break;
    case "ffd8ffe0":
    case "ffd8ffe1":
    case "ffd8ffe2":
      type = "image/jpeg";
      break;
    default:
      type = "unknown";
      break;
  }

  return type;
}

function getHeaderInfo(url, headerString) {

    return( mimeType(headerString));

}


// Check for FileReader support
function fileread(event){

  if (window.FileReader && window.Blob) {


  /* Handle local files */
        var mimetype;
        var mimearray=['image/png','image/jpeg','image/gif'];

        var file = event.target.files[0];



             if(mimearray.indexOf(file.type)===-1 || file.size >= 2 * 1024 * 1024){
                while (imageholder.firstChild) {
                  imageholder.removeChild(imageholder.firstChild);
                } 
                document.getElementById('up').value='';
                console.log("you can't upload this file type");
                file=null;
                return false;   

             }else{

                while (imageholder.firstChild) {
                  imageholder.removeChild(imageholder.firstChild);
                } 
                document.getElementById('up').value='';
                remoteCallback(file.name, file);

             }
        }else {
     // File and Blob are not supported
            console.log('file and blob is not supported');
       } /* Drakes, 2015 */



  } 

    document.getElementById('up').addEventListener('change',fileread,false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide fiddle of the same ? I tried making one but it throws error. `Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null`

Answer (score 2):

First of all: **HTML attribute values should always be encapsulated in double quotes**.

Second, this is a correct example of reading files using html5 API like you tried:
(Also check the documentation for it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

```js
window.onload = function() {

    var fileInput = document.getElementById('up');
    var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('imagehoder');


    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var imageType = /image.*/;

        if (file.type.match(imageType)) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                fileDisplayArea.innerHTML = "";

                var img = new Image();
                img.src = reader.result;

                fileDisplayArea.appendChild(img);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        } else {
            fileDisplayArea.innerHTML = "File not supported!"
        }
    });

}
```

```html
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
        <div id="photouploder">

            <div id="imagehoder"></div>

            <div class="inputWrapper">upload image
                <input class="fileInput" id="up" type="file" name="image" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: thanx for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the 'design purpose' in your question. If the 'design purpose' means UI design (CSS related), then probably this reason doesn't stand since they are totally irrelevant.

Also, the file upload technology is very mature now. There are bunches of open source implements in all languages and are well-tested and easy-to-use I highly recommend you to take a look at them before implementing it yourself.